# why I have negative date by subtraction of two column?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to create a column his values is the subtraction of two column but I found strange values:

```
 Patient["Waiting"] = Patient["Appointment"] - Patient["Scheduled"]

 Scheduled                   Appointment       Waiting
 2016-04-29 18:38:08         2016-04-29        -1 days +05:21:52
```

I wonder why these negative values appear ??

Comment: Your appointment date has no time associated with it, so zero time is assumed (midnight)

Comment: It's just time delta, negative because the appointment has 00:00:00 time which is earlier than scheduled 18:38:08.  You can ``abs`` it if you don't care about direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ explain it better:

> When two datetime objects are subtracted, the result is a timedelta. Depending on which date was larger, the result could be positive or negative.

Also if all values in column have no times, in pandas are not shown.

```
Patient["Waiting"] = Patient["Appointment"] - Patient["Scheduled"]
                     2016-04-29 00:00:00    - 2016-04-29 18:38:08
```

For remove negative timedelatas is possible use [`abs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.abs.html):

```
Patient["Waiting"] = (Patient["Appointment"] - Patient["Scheduled"]).abs()
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. When two datetime objects are subtracted, the result is a timedelta. Depending on which date was larger, the result could be positive or negative. Also, I don't think OP had the order wrong, they just wanted to understand the result. Heck, it doesn't seem like they even know what they want.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ - thank you, again english problem how the best explain it.