# I tried to calculate the time interval between two datetime in python, but the result is not correct

Tags: python, datetime

This is the list that I am using

```
dates = [
    datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 24, 8, 23),
    datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 24, 12, 21),
    datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 23, 17, 13),
    datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 22, 4, 12),
    datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 21, 13, 42),
    datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 21, 12, 34),
    datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 19, 5, 32),
    datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 12, 2, 55),
    datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 11, 10, 10),
    datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 11, 13, 55),
    datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 11, 13, 7)
]
```

And for calculating the time interval I used this:
`dates[0]- dates[1]`
and I got this:
`datetime.timedelta(days=-1, seconds=72120)`
It doesn't make sense at all!! Since datetime(year, month, day, hour, minute, second), the first element in the list is almost 4 hours ahead from the second one. But the result says something completely different.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the result is correct.
"days = -1, seconds=72120 " comes from a normalization of the delta value.

**For calculating the time in hours:**

72.120 s / 60 / 60 ≈ 20h

20h - 24h = -4h

means Date[0] is 4 hours ahead of Date[1]

Answer (score 0):

Dates and numbers work the same way in that if you want to get a positive result, you need to subtract the smaller value from the bigger value, not the other way around.

```
>>> datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 24, 12, 21) - datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 24, 8, 23)
datetime.timedelta(seconds=14280)
```

14280 seconds ~= 4 hours.

If you subtract them the other way (like in your code, subtracting larger from smaller), you get a value that equates to negative 4 hours:

```
>>> datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 24, 8, 23) - datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 24, 12, 21)
datetime.timedelta(days=-1, seconds=72120)
>>> (datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 24, 8, 23) - datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 24, 12, 21)).total_seconds()
-14280.0
```

Note that the default way of expressing this negative delta for formatting purposes is "minus one day plus 72120 seconds"; using `total_seconds()` converts it to simply a number of seconds which makes it a little easier to reason about IMO.

Answer (score 0):

It makes absolutely sense. It does exactly what you asked it to do. You asked to subtract a later date from an earlier date, so the result is negative (1 day = 24 hours; 72120 seconds equals roughly 20 hours) so you have -24h+20h=-4h. If you turn it around you get the exact result:

```
print(dates[1]-dates[0])
```

Out:

```
3:58:00
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to check if value 'a' is higher than 'b'

```
# Simulating the list
case.append(datetime.datetime(2020,8,24,8,23))`
>>> case
[datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 24, 8, 23)]
>>> case.append(datetime.datetime(2020,8,24,12,21))
>>> case
[datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 24, 8, 23), datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 24, 12, 21)]

# Negative value outcome
>>> case[0] - case[1]
datetime.timedelta(days=-1, seconds=72120)
*Positive value outcome*
>>> case[1] - case[0]
datetime.timedelta(seconds=14280)
>>> 14280/60
238.0 (minutes) 
>>> 14280/60/60
3.966666666666667 (hours)
```

This post shows the use of (abs):
[why I have negative date by subtraction of two column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47241632/why-i-have-negative-date-by-subtraction-of-two-column)